# Problems with tcolorbox definition based in beamer colors

Tags: beamer, color, tcolorbox

I want to declare a `tcolorbox` with colors based on current color theme used in beamer.

I've tried with something like

```
colbacktitle=\usebeamercolor[bg]{block title alerted}
```

but it shows errors. Therefore I've managed with following code:

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usecolortheme{rose}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{myalertbox}[2][]{%
    code={%
        \usebeamercolor{block title alerted}
        \colorlet{titlebg}{bg}
        \colorlet{titlefg}{fg}
        \usebeamercolor{block body alerted}
        \colorlet{bodybg}{bg}
        \colorlet{bodyfg}{fg}
    },
    colbacktitle=titlebg, 
    coltitle=titlefg, 
    colback=bodybg,
    colupper=bodyfg,
    title=#2,
    boxrule=0pt,
    sharp corners,
    #1
}

\begin{document} 
\begin{frame}{Testing beamer colors in tcolorbox}

\begin{myalertbox}{Alert tcolorbox}
Some text
\end{myalertbox}

\begin{alertblock}{Beamer alert box}
Some text
\end{alertblock}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

Two questions:

1. Why these boxes show different colors?
2. Do you know a better way of using beamer colors in tcolorbox definitions?

Comment: Interesting question. Is there some opacity setting involved in `beamer`?

Comment: This question really helped me, thanks. I am trying to create boxes that match the environment, and I was simply too surprised that this turned out to be so complicated. Thanks for the fix

Answer (score 6):

The problem is related to the fact, that the background colours are defined as a mixture of the alert colour and the background, e.g. `bg=alerted text.fg!20!bg`. This seems to be a problem for the `tcolourbox`.

As a workaround, explicitly use `white` (instead of `bg`) in the colour definition:

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usecolortheme{rose}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}


\setbeamercolor{block title alerted}{use=alerted text,fg=alerted text.fg,bg=alerted text.fg!20!white}
\setbeamercolor{block body alerted}{parent=normal text,use=block title alerted,bg=block title alerted.bg!50!white}

\newtcolorbox{myalertbox}[2][]{%
    code={%
        \usebeamercolor{block title alerted}
        \colorlet{titlebg}{block title alerted.bg}
        \colorlet{titlefg}{block title alerted.fg}
        \usebeamercolor{block body alerted}
        \colorlet{bodybg}{block body alerted.bg}
        \colorlet{bodyfg}{block body alerted.fg}
    },
    colbacktitle=titlebg, 
    coltitle=titlefg, 
    colback=bodybg,
    colupper=bodyfg,
    title=#2,
    boxrule=0pt,
    sharp corners,
    #1
}

\begin{document} 
\begin{frame}{Testing beamer colors in tcolorbox}

\begin{myalertbox}{Alert tcolorbox}
Some text
\end{myalertbox}

\begin{alertblock}{Beamer alert box}
Some text
\end{alertblock}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've just found `bg` in tcolorbox as being part of `\bgroup`. I don't understand how loading `tcolorbox` can change beamer's `bg` value.

Comment: @Ignasi loading `tcolorbox` does not change beamers bg value, but the bg value inside a tcolorbox is different then outside.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to replicate the look and feel of beamer blocks with a tcolorbox is using the new tcolorbox inner theme (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamertheme-tcolorbox ).

This theme will replace the standard beamer blocks with tcolorboxes, but you can also use it to define your own boxes:

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usecolortheme{rose}
\useinnertheme{tcolorbox}

\makeatletter
\newtcolorbox{myalertbox}[2][]{%
    code={%
      \beamer@tcb@colini[ alerted]
    },
    colback=beamer@tcb@bodybg,
    colbacktitle=beamer@tcb@titlebg,
    coltext=beamer@tcb@bodyfg,
    coltitle=beamer@tcb@titlefg,
    before title={\usebeamerfont{block title alerted}},
    before upper={\usebeamerfont{block body alerted}},    
    title=#2,
    #1
}
\makeatother

\begin{document} 
\begin{frame}{Testing beamer colors in tcolorbox}

\begin{myalertbox}{Alert tcolorbox}
Some text
\end{myalertbox}

\begin{alertblock}{Beamer alert box}
Some text
\end{alertblock}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]